# Android App - New Activity not opening

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

In my android app, I have a navigation drawer menu and its populated with a string array. When i click the individual strings I want to open a new activity (both are fragment activities). This does not work as I thought it would. Any other ways suitable?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    SelectItem(position);
}

public void SelectItem(int position) {
    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);

    Intent testIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);

    //for example:
    if (position == 2) {
        startActivity(testIntent);
    }
}
```

logcat error: http://pastebin.com/v8pbpC0S

this is the class "AnotherActivity" 's contents: http://pastebin.com/zEymwJNQ
Judging by the logcat I believe the error occurs here.

Comment: Have you added AnotherActivity to your manifest file?

Comment: first remove line `if (position == 2)`

Comment: @activesince93 im going to change it to a case statement. this is just a test.

Comment: are u able to debug I meant have u tried by putting a break point. Is that hitting?

Comment: @Raghavendra ive updated my original post with a pastebin of the logcat error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `NullPointerException` at line 33

```
com.ex.app.AnotherActivity.onCreate(AnotherActivity.java:33)
```

Looks like `ListView` reference is `null`.

Comment: if you take a look at my second pastebin (obviously different lines because i dont have the import lines, etc) the list view is clearly initialized.

Comment: Are you referencing the right ID from your XML file like R.id.drawerList? because logcat is clear listview is null

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.drawerList)` can return `null` value.